# Does ruby expression expansion via #{} do double expansion?

Tags: ruby, expression, expansion

Okay, per suggestions on clarifying the intent I have restated the question.  Hope this example is clear.

```
$funcname = ""
$message = ""
$DebugFormat = "Within #{$funcname} message: #{$message}"


def Something
   $funcname = "Something"
   # .
   # .
   # .
   $message = "an important message."
   puts "#{$DebugFormat}"

end

def Another
   $funcname = "Another"
   # Another method related code ...
   $message = "Result message to output"
   puts "#{$DebugFormat}"
end
```

So, the idea is to have various debug related strings to use in various places without needing to repeat the same formatting and such.

Anyway, this isn't super critical it's more just an attempt to try and learn Ruby better.

go easy,

-daniel

Comment: I have to ask - _why_ do you want to do this? There's a very very high probability that this is an indicator of a poor design decision.

Comment: hmm, I thought it was clear what the purpose would be for given the example ...  I would like to specify one global string for debugging output and have method specific values reflected programmatically when the string is written.

Comment: I agree with Jamie. I don't know what you mean by 'method specific values' as you haven't shown us any methods, but I think a much more elegant solution could be given if we were to know your _real_ problem better. What, specifically, are you trying to achieve? Please amend your question.

Comment: I've modified the question - hope it helps.

Comment: What language does this sort of expansion? I'm so curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible as you have shown. the `#{}` syntax is just for string interpolation, so when you write `PP = "[#{fname}]"`, it's simply storing the string `[Empty]` in the variable `PP`. Strings have no memory of what code was used to produce them.

It's unclear what you're attempting to achieve with this, but more than likely a method would be more appropriate than string interpolation.

---

**Update since your edit:** It seems you want to create a sort of simulated stack trace. String interpolation still doesn't make sense. Instead, you could do something like this:

```
def debug(message)
  puts "#{ caller[0][/`([^']*)'/, 1]}: #{message}"
end

def something
  debug "an important message"
end

def another
  debug "result message to output"
end

something
another
```

Based on your strange usage of global variables and constants, it seems you're trying to apply ideas from some other language in ways that don't fit with Ruby. I'd recommend looking through a Ruby book to get familiar with the basics.

Comment: A method would definitely be the standard solution, but I tried to do this string expansion, and then ... well you know how the rabbit hole opens ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval for this.
Just make sure to make "XXX" a very unlikely string to appear in actual message.

```
$DebugFormat = 'Within #{$funcname} message: #{$message}'

def somefunc
   $funcname = "Something"
   $message = "an important message."
   puts eval("<<XXX\n" + $DebugFormat + "\nXXX\n")
end
```